# How can i access an element from 2 structures pointers ?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, struct, casting

I have a pointer & 2 different structures. The first structure has a member that is a void* pointer. Now i need to access a member of the second structure using the previous pointer to the first structure.

```
struct a {
  void *ptrxx;
}

struct b {
  int info;
}

struct a *ptr;
```

I need to do something like :

```
 ptr->ptrxx->info;
```

But i have to do some kind of typecasting to let C know that `ptr->ptrxx` is a pointer to struct b. How can i do this in one expression (without the need of an extra pointer) ?

PS:I'm getting `error: request for member ***** in something not a structure or union.` (gcc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((struct b *)(ptr->ptrxx))->info
```

Probably don't need all those parens, but it helps to show the order of what's happenning.  Take the `ptrxx` member of `struct a` (which is a `void *`), cast it into a pointer to `struct b`, then take the `info` member of that.